# check embed tag exist javascript

Tags: javascript, tags, embed, append, element

How can I check if embed tag exist in my html.
I've created this tag through javascript

```
    soundEmbed = document.createElement("embed");
    soundEmbed.setAttribute("src", "notify.wav");
    soundEmbed.setAttribute("hidden", true);
    soundEmbed.setAttribute("autostart", true);
    soundEmbed.setAttribute("loop", false);
    document.body.appendChild(soundEmbed);
```

but since I am using autorefresh and appendChild, every time it refresh it creates additional sound.

Using appendChild, I think I've got many embed tags. That's what I think maybe the cause of additional sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `soundEmbed.id = "__soundEmbed";` before appending. Then, surround the entire thing with:

```
if( !document.getElementById("__soundEmbed")) {
    soundEmbed = ......;
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could give the element an id and check this first:

```
if (!document.getElementById('someId')) {
  var soundEmbed = document.createElement("embed");
  soundEmbed.setAttribute("src", "notify.wav");
  soundEmbed.setAttribute("hidden", true);
  soundEmbed.setAttribute("autostart", true);
  soundEmbed.setAttribute("loop", false);
  soundEmbed.setAttribute("id", 'someId');
  document.body.appendChild(soundEmbed);
}
```

Or alternatively, check against a flag (since soundEmbed seems to be defined elsewhere we can use a falsey check on it):

```
if (!soundEmbed) {
  soundEmbed = document.createElement("embed");
  soundEmbed.setAttribute("src", "notify.wav");
  soundEmbed.setAttribute("hidden", true);
  soundEmbed.setAttribute("autostart", true);
  soundEmbed.setAttribute("loop", false);
  document.body.appendChild(soundEmbed);
}
```

Comment: Can I just remove the element? Then add the child? I need this way for a reason. Sample: `if (document.getElementById('soundId')) document.body.removeChild('soundId');` Is this right?

Comment: How can I play the sound if soundEmbed exist? It only plays when there is no soundEmbed

Answer (score 0):

It won't be in your HTML, but it will be in the DOM tree (you're adding it to the DOM after the HTML has been parsed, so it never sees any HTML). A super-simple solution is to just maintain a global variable that tells you whether it's been created yet or not - just initialize it to `false`, and set it to `true` when you create the `embed` element.